# Preventing predictable modifications to AES encrypted data

Tags: attack, known-plaintext-attack

I'm fairly new to cryptography and am trying to find out best practice for this situation. Let's say I have some code which is going to be used to pass around an encrypted e-mail address. I encrypt it and pass the encoded data out in a link:

```
// pass in "bill@microsoft.com"
public String encryptMessage(final String message) throws Exception {
    // cipher created with Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.get().init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.get().doFinal(message.getBytes());

    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.get().getParameters();
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    byte[] data = Arrays.copyOf(iv, iv.length + cipherText.length);
    System.arraycopy(cipherText, 0, data, iv.length, cipherText.length);
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(data);
}
```

Now, the recipient passes back the generated string, but guesses the first 16 bytes are the IV (is this a nonce?) and makes a modification to them which creates a (semi-)predicatable change in the encrypted data. For example, the change to byte 5 in the code below changes "bill@microsoft.com" to "bill@oicrosoft.com" or "bill@kicrosoft.com" in most cases. (Let's say I want to register these domains to intercept e-mails):

```
public String decryptMessage(final String message) throws Exception {
    byte[] encData = Base64.decodeBase64(message);

    encData[5] += 2; // Attacker modifies IV to create a predictable change in the data
    cipher.get().init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(encData, 0, 16)));
    byte[] plaintext = cipher.get().doFinal(Arrays.copyOfRange(encData, 16, encData.length));
    return new String(plaintext);
}
```

What should I be doing to prevent this - is this a case where I should be using some sort of digital signing to ensure an attacker cannot change the data, or is there a better way of using encryption here?

Comment: If you can afford some overhead (typically 16 bytes) you can use authenticated encryption. Which will reject any modified message with very high probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [authenticated mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) such as [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode).  You can't prevent the modification, but you can detect it.

Comment: That looks like it will do what I need. I assume this basically does the same as if I did what I was doing originally, and just added a MAC afterwards?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it.